# Using accordian() inside backbone.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I have a question with using jquery inside backbone.js view. Firstly, please correct me if I am wrong but I am under the assumption that this.$el which refers to the backbone view is a points to the correct cached jquery object. 
I am trying to call a jquery function on this.$el and the one I am specifically calling is the accordian(). So, the code that gives me error is the line - 
"this.$el.accordian()"

Following is my code, please take a look:
http://pastebin.com/fabpypVZ

You will have to host it somewhere. I hosted it locally and it worked.

As a side note I have checked all the questions on this issue in stack overflow. I have still been unable to work this out. I may be doing something silly like not including something important but i haven't found what that something important is.

Comment: checkout this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422614/how-do-we-implement-a-jquery-date-picker-in-a-backbone-application/24423010#24423010

Comment: What is the error it is throwing?

Comment: Is there any reason you are including jQuery 3 times? That said you might be better off creating a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: No good reason. It was just to make sure I am importing the needed jquery page. Only because I am using content delivery network . But I assume they should reliable enough.

Comment: the error it throws is undefined function.

Comment: Here is a better pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ck6XFyAU

Comment: @ProgrammerForNow Actually it is not a good idea to include jQuery more than once. That said it seems to work fine, have a look at this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gocetude/1/).